# How to display date like NOVEMBER 13, 2020 in azure data factory using mapping dataflow?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I want to display date like NOVEMBER 13,2020. Requesting you to suggest how can i achieve it using azure data factory mapping dataflow.

Thanks in Advance!!

Regards,
Ashok

Comment: what's the source data look like? If you want to do that, "NOVEMBER 13,2020" must a string data.

Comment: Hi Leon Yue, Thank you so much for your response, source data look like this "2020-02-12"

Comment: Hi @Ashok Kumar Bollineni, please see my answer, I give the solution. If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: @Leon Yue, Thank you so much, I have accept it as a answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Data Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview) to achieve that.

Create a Source with your data like this:
[image]

Please set the data "2020-02-12" as String data.

Then using [Derived column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column) to build the expression to achieve that output:

```
concat(case(month(toDate(d))==1,'January',month(toDate(d))==2,'February',month(toDate(d))==3,'March',month(toDate(d))==4,'April',month(toDate(d))==5,'May',month(toDate(d))==6,'June',month(toDate(d))==7,'July',month(toDate(d))==8,'August',month(toDate(d))==9,'September',month(toDate(d))==10,'October',month(toDate(d))==11,'November',month(toDate(d))==12,'December'),',' ,toString(dayOfMonth(toDate(d))),',',toString(year(toDate(d))))
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

After doing this, you can get the output you want.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You should use toString(dateCol, 'with date format'). You can find all date formats from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

You can use 'L' and experiment with what format you desire.